# Update panel Avoid page reload when Radio button is checked not working

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use 2 Radio buttons and swap the view according to the radio button selected, but it's not working, the page does not reload and nothing happens.
can someone tell me where is the problem?

```
        <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin Part/Admin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataEntry.aspx.cs" Inherits="_4Kids.Admin_Part.DataEntry" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
        
        <%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
        <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>           <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
                                        <td style="height: 21px;">
                
                                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdb_Preterm" runat="server" Text="Preterm" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdb_Preterm_CheckedChanged" />
                                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdb_Fulterm" runat="server" Text="Full term" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdb_Fulterm_CheckedChanged" />
                
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="height: 21px;">
                                            <asp:MultiView ID="Mul" runat="server">
                                                <asp:View ID="view_null" runat="server"></asp:View>
                                                <asp:View ID="view_weeks" runat="server">
                                                    <table>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Weeks:"></asp:Label>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_pretermWeeks" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </asp:View>
                                            </asp:MultiView>
                                        </td>
</tr>
</table>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdb_Preterm" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdb_Fulterm" EventName="CheckedChanged"/>
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:
In your posted markup, I don't seen anything related to the ajaxtoolkit.

So, remove that stuff. Also, remove the post back triggers. They are really for causing OTHER update panels to trigger - and you don't have multiple panels, so dump that stuff.

You do however need the script manager due to use of the update panel.

So, we now have this:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td style="height: 21px;">                
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdb_Preterm" runat="server"
                    Text="Preterm" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdb_Preterm_CheckedChanged" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdb_Fulterm" runat="server" 
                    Text="Full term" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdb_Fulterm_CheckedChanged" />                
            </td>
            <td style="height: 21px;">
                <asp:MultiView ID="Mul" runat="server">
                    <asp:View ID="view_null" runat="server"></asp:View>
                    <asp:View ID="view_weeks" runat="server">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Weeks:"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_pretermWeeks" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:View>
                </asp:MultiView>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And you code behind can be this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void rdb_Preterm_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdb_Preterm.Checked)
        {
            rdb_Fulterm.Checked = false;
            Mul.SetActiveView(view_null);
        }
    }

    protected void rdb_Fulterm_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdb_Fulterm.Checked)
        {
            rdb_Preterm.Checked = false;
            Mul.SetActiveView(view_weeks);
        }
    }
```

That's all you really should need here. As noted, no need for the triggers, you ALREADY have postback=true for the radio buttons.

Comment: The only problem is that the page fully reloads...

Comment: Even when you use a update panel,  then you get what is called a partial page post back. So on page load will fire, but you shouldn't get a full page post back. So for any controls and buttons etc in the update panel that does a post back, your limited to the panel.  Any page setup code in page load event still needs to be placed inside of a if not Post back code stub. But you shouldn't be seeing a full page post back.

Comment: That's the problem I am seeing a full page post back. I think that there's something missing i am not paying attention to.

Comment: If you see the browser spin icon that shows during a page load or refresh, then yes something is wrong. I assume your page load code is inside of if (!IsPostBack) . But if you see the browser spin button, then yes you have a issue. Check for missing close tags, but we missing something here. I assume in the past you used update panels and they work fine

Comment: Yes I am seeing browser spin button, and the page totally refreshes and goes back to the top of it, all I was trying to achieve is  that partial rendering of the multiview without the whole reload. is there another way though?

Comment: Hum, it looks like you using a master page. That also should be ok, but I would check the code in the site master page - and specific check what the page.load event does. That page load event (in master) will FIRE on first page load. But after that, each post-back should not trigger the masters page load event. I would take a quick look. As I stated, you have used with success the update panel before - or is this the first time and you never had any update panel work?